# Why is there no output with this javascript code? What am I missing?

Tags: javascript

Here is some sample code I wrote because I have a harder assignment that isn't working, and now, I cant even get this to work. Just trying to display the output of adding two numbers together, what am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Add() {
            var n1 = document.getElementById("numOne").value;
            var n2 = document.getElementById("numTwo").value;
            var total = n1 + n2;

            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = total;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calc</h1><br />
    <form method="post" action="">
        NUM 1: <input type="number" name="numOne" id="numOne" /><br />

        NUM 2: <input type="number" name="numTwo" id="numTwo" /><br />

        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="ADD()" /><br />

        Result: <label id="output"></label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ADD()` != `Add()`. You should learn some basic debugging skills like using the browser's dev tools, especially the console. It would show you things like this immediately. You're also concatenating two strings together, so you should convert them to numbers before outputting the result.

Comment: `onclick="Add()"`?

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." – Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive.  Add and ADD are different.

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. It will tell you that `ADD` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the case of the function name when referencing it. `ADD()` should be `Add()`. Please consult your developer console for error messages.

Also, if you want to sum the two numbers, you'll need to convert them from strings first so that you're not performing concatenation.

```
    function Add() {
        var n1 = document.getElementById("numOne").value;
        var n2 = document.getElementById("numTwo").value;
        var total = parseInt(n1, 10) + parseInt(n2, 10);

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = total;
    }
```

Here I used `parseInt()` with a radix of `10` to convert the numeric strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`ADD()` => change to `Add()` (Javascript is case-sensitive)

`Number()` function to convert string to number. Works perfectly, run it and see. (If you don't put this, and your inputs are, say, `5` and `6`, then your output will be `56` (string concatenation) and not `11`)

```html
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Add() {
            var n1 = document.getElementById("numOne").value;
            var n2 = document.getElementById("numTwo").value;
            var total = Number(n1) + Number(n2); // Number() function

            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = total;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calc</h1><br />
    <form method="post" action="">
        NUM 1: <input type="number" name="numOne" id="numOne" /><br />

        NUM 2: <input type="number" name="numTwo" id="numTwo" /><br />

        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="Add()" /><br />

        Result: <label id="output"></label>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the output shows up now. But my assignment still isnt working. Round 2?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Round 2?!! Try adding the `html` tags and the `<!DOCTYPE html>` if you are working on your PC and not on a place like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The function names are case sensitive, you need change this:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="ADD()" /><br />
```

To this:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="Add()" /><br />
```